# How can raging song be activated in less than a standard action before level 7?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, skald

At levels 1 through 7 the [skald](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/)'s supernatural ability [raging song](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald/#TOC-Raging-Song-Su-)  normally takes a standard action to start. Is there a way to start a raging song in less than a standard action before level 7, like with a feat or magic item?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. While the site generally frowns on expansive list questions, short lists—like I'm almost certain this one will be—are totally allowed. I edited the question to add the links and did a little tuning; I hope that's okay, and the question can be edited further or rolled back if the changes are too much. Anyway, have fun and enjoy the site.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to make sure to add links and be more precise in the future.

Comment: I was actually looking for an answer to exactly this question earlier today, and have not found anything. I've found a few items that raise your effective bard level for bardic performance (which raging song counts as), but they all specify what they increase, rather than just being general increases, and none of them will do what we're looking for here.

Answer (score 6):

### Singing Steel special material

The new [Adventurer's Armory 2](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9q01?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Adventurers-Armory-2) includes a new special material called Singing Steel. This new material includes this ability:

> When wielding a singing steel weapon, shield, or item
>   weighing at least 5 pounds, or wearing medium or heavy singing
>   steel armor, the wielder or wearer can strike the singing steel
>   as part of beginning a bardic performance. If the wielder can
>   normally start a bardic performance as a standard action, he
>   can do so as a move action instead. **If the wielder can normally
>   start a bardic performance as a move action, he can do so as a
>   swift action instead.** This ability does not function in the area
>   of a silence spell or similar eﬀect. After using the singing steel in
>   this fashion, the steel must be carefully brushed to remove any
>   lingering vibrations, a process that takes 10 minutes.

This works because of this line, making [Raging Song](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/skald#TOC-Raging-Song-Su-) count as Bardic Performance:

> A raging song counts as the bard’s bardic performance special ability for any effect that affects bardic performances.

Singing Steel also increases the maximum Dexterity bonus by 1, reduces the arcane spell failure by 5%, and reduces the Armor Check Penalty by 1 if used to make armor, or counts as alchemical silver for a weapon.

- Light armor: +750gp  **Note:** Light armor does not qualify for the action reduction
- Medium armor: +9000gp
- Heavy armor: +12000gp
- Shield: +7000gp
- Weapon: +6000gp
- Other items: +600gp/lb **Note:** Must be at least 5lbs to qualify for the action reduction

This is the only way I can find to reduce the action required to start a bardic performance/raging song.

---

I've come across another item that technically allows you to reduce the action needed to start a bardic performance/raging song.

[Perfect Tuning Fork](http://archivesofnethys.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Perfect%20Tuning%20Fork) is a one time use 600gp item that allows you to reduce the action.

> When holding a perfect tuning fork in the hand, the wielder can strike the fork as part of the action of beginning a bardic performance. If the wielder can start a bardic performance as a standard action, she can do so as a move action instead. **If the wielder can start a bardic performance as a move action, she can do so as a swift action instead.** A perfect tuning fork loses its magic after one use, but it can be used as an ordinary tuning fork thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Rage powers, Savage Intuition.
https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/savage-intuition/

> **Benefit:** Your bestial senses allow you to sense danger and become enraged before you even have time to consciously react to danger. When combat begins, if you have rounds of rage remaining, you may automatically enter a rage without using an action at the start of the first round of combat (or at the start of the surprise round, if there is one), even if you are not otherwise aware that combat has begun.

Seems legit to me.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] as an introduction and check the [help] for further guidance. This answer as is effectively just pointing at a feature. Could you complete the answer by explaining how this feature can be used to solve the problem posed in the question? Good luck and happy gaming!